# How to use mingw32 when installing a distutils package?

Tags: python, git, bash, distutils, git-bash

I've come across [a github project](https://github.com/andrewschoen/django-cms-demo) which I am trying to install and run it but I've run into some problems. I've also put this up [as an issue](https://github.com/andrewschoen/django-cms-demo/issues/2). The entire pip log is available there.

The problem appears to revolve around distutils, if I understand correctly:

> f:\python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown
>   distribution option: 'use_2to3'  warnings.warn(msg)  error: Unable to
>   find vcvarsall.bat

Looking this up I was directed to [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/10558328#10558328).

Now checking my system I have MS Visual C++ 2005,2008,2010 all installed.I don't have visual studio. I am using win 7 with git-bash which has MINGW32 installed. In the above thread fpessoa discusses `setup.py install build --compiler=mingw32`. I decided to try the following :

1. I had python 2.7 already installed.
2. Added mingw32's bin directory to environment variable: append **PATH** with `f:\git\bin;`
3. Created **distutils.cfg** located at `C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg` to:

   ```
   [build]
   compiler=mingw32
   ```

Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.

Is this the same thing as executing `setup.py install build --compiler=mingw32` ? If not how do I get setup.py to use the --compiler=mingw32 argument when it reads requirement.txt?

The contents of my f:\git\bin are:

```
drwxr-xr-x   19 bsmith     Administ        0 Nov 23 10:33 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   215040 Oct 23 03:26 antiword.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ      540 Jun 27  2012 astextplain
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ      170 Jun 27  2012 awk
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    18432 Oct 23 03:26 basename.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   540672 Oct 23 03:26 bash.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ  1299968 Oct 23 03:26 bison.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ      188 Jun 27  2012 bunzip2
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    75264 Oct 23 03:26 bzip2.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ     3802 Jun 27  2012 c_rehash
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    22528 Oct 23 03:26 cat.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    28160 Oct 23 03:26 chmod.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ      103 Jun 27  2012 clear
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    11264 Oct 23 03:26 cmp.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    52224 Oct 23 03:26 connect.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    74240 Oct 23 03:26 cp.exe
-rw-r--r--    1 bsmith     Administ   227107 Jul 10  2012 curl-ca-bundle.
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   404992 Oct 23 03:26 curl.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    24064 Oct 23 03:26 cut.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    47616 Oct 23 03:26 date.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    68608 Oct 23 03:26 diff.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    17920 Oct 23 03:26 dirname.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    11763 Jun 27  2012 docx2txt
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    15872 Oct 23 03:26 dos2unix.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    65536 Oct 23 03:26 du.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ      171 Jun 27  2012 echo
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ      175 Jun 27  2012 egrep
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    18944 Oct 23 03:26 env.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    49152 Oct 23 03:26 expr.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    12288 Oct 23 03:26 false.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    52224 Oct 23 03:26 find.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ  1330176 Oct 23 03:26 flex.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   149504 Oct 23 03:26 gawk.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ     5632 Oct 23 03:26 getcp.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ  1363968 Oct 23 03:26 git-receive-pac
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ  1363968 Oct 23 03:26 git-upload-arch
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   654848 Oct 23 03:26 git-upload-pack
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ  1363968 Oct 23 03:26 git.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   330727 Oct 22 17:01 gitk
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ     3374 Feb 28  2009 gpg-zip
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   486448 Feb 28  2009 gpg.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    64309 Feb 28  2009 gpgsplit.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   217749 Feb 28  2009 gpgv.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    81408 Oct 23 03:26 grep.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    50688 Oct 23 03:26 gunzip.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    50688 Oct 23 03:26 gzip.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    26624 Oct 23 03:26 head.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    21504 Oct 23 03:26 id.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    10240 Oct 23 03:26 kill.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   112128 Oct 23 03:26 less.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   812063 Jun 27  2012 libW11.dll
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   200015 Jun 27  2012 libapr-0-0.dll
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   146280 Jun 27  2012 libaprutil-0-0.
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ  1723196 Jun  6  2012 libcrypto.dll
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   411907 Jan 12  2012 libcurl-4.dll
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   184599 Jun 27  2012 libexpat-0.dll
-rw-r--r--    1 bsmith     Administ     7465 Jan 12  2012 libgsasl-7.def
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   443550 Jan 12  2012 libgsasl-7.dll
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ  1241889 May 31  2012 libiconv-2.dll
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   978432 Feb 28  2009 libiconv2.dll
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   177216 Jun 27  2012 libneon-25.dll
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ  4884531 Jan 12  2012 libpoppler-7.dl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   378238 Jun  6  2012 libssl.dll
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   255849 Jun 27  2012 libsvn_client-1
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    77401 Jun 27  2012 libsvn_delta-1-
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    57948 Jun 27  2012 libsvn_diff-1-0
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    49557 Jun 27  2012 libsvn_fs-1-0.d
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   172387 Jun 27  2012 libsvn_fs_fs-1-
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    37342 Jun 27  2012 libsvn_ra-1-0.d
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   181083 Jun 27  2012 libsvn_ra_dav-1
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    62039 Jun 27  2012 libsvn_ra_local
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   123176 Jun 27  2012 libsvn_ra_svn-1
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   202003 Jun 27  2012 libsvn_repos-1-
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   266235 Jun 27  2012 libsvn_subr-1-0
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    73712 Jun 27  2012 libsvn_swig_per

-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   284454 Jun 27  2012 libsvn_wc-1-0.d
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   194947 Jun 27  2012 libz.dll
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    72704 Oct 23 03:26 ln.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    69632 Oct 23 03:26 ls.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   200192 Oct 23 03:26 m4.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    27648 Oct 23 03:26 md5sum.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    28672 Oct 23 03:26 mkdir.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   108544 Oct 23 03:26 msmtp.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   743240 Feb 10  2012 msys-1.0.dll
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ  1325053 Jun 27  2012 msys-crypto-0.9
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    19968 Jun 27  2012 msys-minires.dl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   939520 Jun 27  2012 msys-perl5_8.dl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    82852 Jun 27  2012 msys-regex-1.dl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   317994 Jun 27  2012 msys-ssl-0.9.8.
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    91792 Jun 27  2012 msys-z.dll
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    52064 Jun 27  2012 msysltdl-3.dll
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    81408 Oct 23 03:26 mv.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   353280 Oct 23 03:26 openssl.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    57344 Oct 23 03:26 patch.exe
-rw-r--r--    1 bsmith     Administ      570 Feb 28  2009 patch.exe.manif
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    28160 Oct 23 03:26 pdfinfo.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    29184 Oct 23 03:26 pdftotext.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ     7168 Oct 23 03:26 perl.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ      175 Jun 27  2012 printf
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    10240 Oct 23 03:26 ps.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    65124 Jun 27  2012 pthreadGC2.dll
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ      169 Jun 27  2012 pwd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   303616 Oct 23 03:26 rebase.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ     2137 Jun 27  2012 recodetree
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    62464 Oct 23 03:26 rm.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    22528 Oct 23 03:26 rmdir.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   102400 Oct 23 03:26 rxvt.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    43008 Oct 23 03:26 scp.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ  1146880 Oct 23 03:26 sed.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   540672 Oct 23 03:26 sh.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    18432 Oct 23 03:26 sleep.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    39936 Oct 23 03:26 sort.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    23552 Oct 23 03:26 split.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    81920 Oct 23 03:26 ssh-add.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    69632 Oct 23 03:26 ssh-agent.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   109056 Oct 23 03:26 ssh-keygen.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   144384 Oct 23 03:26 ssh-keyscan.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   256000 Oct 23 03:26 ssh.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ      192 Jun 27  2012 start
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    35840 Oct 23 03:26 tail.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ  1353728 Oct 23 03:26 tar.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   843776 Jan 12  2012 tcl85.dll
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    16384 Jan 12  2012 tclpip85.dll
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ     7680 Oct 23 03:26 tclsh.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ     7680 Oct 23 03:26 tclsh85.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    19456 Oct 23 03:26 tee.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ  1011712 Jan 12  2012 tk85.dll
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    38400 Oct 23 03:26 touch.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    33280 Oct 23 03:26 tr.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    12288 Oct 23 03:26 true.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    18944 Oct 23 03:26 uname.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    24576 Oct 23 03:26 uniq.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ   159232 Oct 23 03:26 unzip.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ       45 Jun 27  2012 vi
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ       45 Jun 27  2012 vim
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    32256 Oct 23 03:26 wc.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ      173 Jun 27  2012 which
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    10240 Oct 23 03:26 wish.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    10240 Oct 23 03:26 wish85.exe
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bsmith     Administ    12288 Oct 23 03:26 xargs.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on the web but havn't tested it:
   install MinGW . in the MinGW's bin dictionary **find mingw32-make.exe, copy it and rename as make.exe**
   other procedures are the same as in your question.

Comment: Hi Luyi, Thanks for looking. I am using git-bash which includes minGW32 if I understand correctly. I've added the bin directory contents above to the question. I don't see 'mingw32-make.exe'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error; and solution explained in that post was not working. 
My solution was to install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and use its python as a default python for my windows.
Note: Default version of python on cygwin is 2.6

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using Python 2.7 for this project, but your error message:

UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'use_2to3' warnings.warn(msg) error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

refers to the 2to3 utility that converts Python 2.x to Python 3.x syntax.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Are you sure you are using all Python 2.7 libraries that appropriate for your operating system?

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to find an answer using https://zignar.net/2012/06/17/install-python-on-windows/.

Thanks for your help. As it turns out I now understand that GIT-BASH does not contain a compiler which is what ming32w has within it.

Regards,

Bill